# WPF and MVVM problem

Tags: wpf, mvvm, delegatecommand

if try implemnt my first MVVM in WPF app. I have old app based on winforms and I want use my logic (class) from this project.

I have Model, it consist with these classes:

```
public class FriendData
{
//...
}

public class PingData
{
//...
}

public class PokecAccount : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
//...
}


public class Rp :INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
//...
}


public class JsonUser:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
//...
}
```

And service class which send HTTP GET and POST request on server, this class implement this interface:

```
interface IPokecService
{
    bool LogOn(string nick, string password);
    bool LogOff();
    JsonUser CreateJsonUser(string nick);
    void Ping();
    void IbRp();
    bool SendRp(Rp rp);
    Rp LoadRp();
}


public class PokecService:IPokec
{
 public PokecAccount account;
 public PingData pingData;

 //impelent interface IPokec

}
```

I try use DelegateCommand from WPF Model-View-ViewModel Toolkit 0.1.

With View I have any problem. But my problem is how "wrap" methods from class PokecService in ViewModel.

Example with method LogOn.

First I create **View.**

**StartUpWindow.xaml**

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,12,12,12">
        <Label Name="lbAzetID" Content="AzetID" Style="{StaticResource lb1}"></Label>
        <TextBox Name="tbAzetID" Style="{StaticResource tb1}">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="AzetId" Mode="OneWayToSource" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <Label Name="lbRegistration" Content="Registrácia" Style="{StaticResource lb1}">
            <Label.ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Registrácia</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Nemáte vlástené AzetID, registrujte sa tu!</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Label.ToolTip>
        </Label>
        <Label Name="lbPassword" Content="Heslo" Style="{StaticResource lb1}" ></Label>
        <TextBox Name="tbPassword" Style="{StaticResource tb1}">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Password" Mode="OneWayToSource" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <Label Name="lbForgetPassword" Content="Zabudli ste heslo?" Style="{StaticResource lb1}">
            <Label.ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Zabudli ste svoje heslo?</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Nechajte si ho zaslať na Váš email.</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Label.ToolTip>
        </Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Name="LogOn"
            Command="{Binding LogOnCommand}"
            Content="Prihlásiť" 
            Width="100" 
            Height="25" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Row="2" />
```

It consist only 2 texboxes and one button, I bind button commad on property of ViewModel.

**VieModel
StartUpViewModel.cs**

In this class I want wrap methods from class PokecService on DelegateCommand, and these bind on UI controls.

```
public class StartUpViewModel
{

    private string _name = "KecMessanger";
    private string _password = "KecMessanger";
    private PokecService _pokecService;

    public StartUpViewModel()
    {
        _pokecService=new PokecService();
    }

    DelegateCommand _logOnCommand;

    public ICommand LogOnCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if(_logOnCommand==null)
            {
                _logOnCommand=new DelegateCommand(LogOn,CanLogOn);
            }
            return _logOnCommand;
        }
    }

    private void LogOn()
    {
        //In this method I need to call method LogOn from calss PokecService _pokecService.LogOn(_name,_password)          
        //if loging is success I need create another window - view and close this window
        //somehing like this:
        if (_pokecService.LogOn(_name, _password))
        {
            var newViewWindow = new AnotherView();
            //close StartUpView (its typeof window) but I don’t know how
            AnotherView.Show();
        }           
    }

    private bool CanLogOn()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. I can bind UI controls from view on properties in ViewModel, it is no problem.
   It is good way to "wrap" methods from my class PokecService in ViewModel with DelegateCommad?
2. It is good create new window/View in ViewModel ? How can I close actual View(Window) in ViewModel?
3. What is the most suitable solution for this problem?

I think I need only wrap my methods with DelegateCommand variable, and create for these variable properties and this properties bind on UI controls but I am absolute beginner in MVVM. I read some articles, but they show only very simple demo.

Thank for any advance. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Commands are made to communicate between view and viewmodel in MVVM. To abstract the PokecService away from the ViewModel, I'd advise you to use Dependency Injection (I myself use [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com)).
2. I would supply the view with dependency injection, so the class is easier testable. Create an interface if needed so you could replace the actual implementation of the service class without replacing the type everywhere.
3. use a DI container.

Note: I use [WAF](http://waf.codeplex.com/) as MVVM framework together with MEF and it works like a charm.

Short Example:

```
[Export(typeof(IService))]
public class Service : IService
{
}

public interface IService
{
  void Method();
}

[Export]
public class Consumer
{
  private readonly IService _Service;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public Consumer(IService service)
  {
    ser = service;
  }


  public void DoStuff()
  {
    //stuff
    _Service.Method();
  }
}
```

In a startup method (ie. `Application.OnStartup`):

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); //insert the assembly defining the mentioned classes above
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.ComposeParts(this);

Consumer c = container.GetExportedValue<Consumer>();
c.DoStuff();
```

Comment: How can I use dependency injection on PokecService methods? It seems complicated.

Comment: Oki, thank for example, maybe I look as dumb, but it is my first WPF app. You use in example reflection on load class Consumer which expose Service class. But I must also use instance of consumer class in DelegetCommand method. It is no same?

Comment: The `AssemblyCatalog` is one of the ways to generate the dependency trees in MEF, it has nothing to do with your implementation of the classes, and reflection is used there to get the executing assembly for parsing. As I said, Commands are for communication between the view and viewmodel, and not viewmodel and services.

Comment: Ok, I now understand. Thnak for a help, I try use MEF.

Comment: Just a note: You usually have a Controller that starts the application, and that should be the only object you get out of the container explicitly. Everything else is just interaction between classes.

Comment: Oki, I start only with WPF, 3 years I use only winforms. Wpf is something diferent as winforms.

Comment: Yep, that's true, I had the some problems switching from winforms to wpf + DI and mvvm. Took some time to make the switch, but I never looked back.

Comment: You are right, thank for your help. MVVM is good, but in examples you don’t find how can you use other other class in ViewModel for example. Example are very very simple, often no from real world.